# Can a custom web api using Azure AD App Only token get throttled by SharePoint Online?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

I have 02 custom web api. One using user and password and another using Azure AD App Only token to connect to SharePoint Online. None of them are performing batch activities, but simple CRUD activities. However sometimes the custom web api, using user and password, got throttled, recieving a 503 "Server too busy" response from SharePoint Online. I'm planning to change that authentication to Azure AD App Only token, because I never receive that reponse when using Azure AD App Only token. Or maybe it's something related to the amount of resource quota assigned to the site collection.

- Custome Web API using user and password is deployed on premise server.
- Custome Web API using Azure AD App Only token is deployed on an App Service in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is really not an answer to your question. When SharePoint throttles your request, it will send you **429 Too many requests** or **503 Server too busy**, with information (response header Retry-After) when you should try again.

Throttling works at user basis. So one user (making a lot of requests) could be throttled but another user not. I am not sure if this apply to App-Only (probably yes), but throttling is just a mechanism to regulate number of requests to ensure that the server is not overhwelmed by requests by one user. You have some options to avoid getting throttled, see reference bellow.

You can also try to check response header **X-SharePointHealthScore** (this header is in all responses) to check how much the server is busy. This header contains number from 1 to 10 when 10 means that SharePoint server is under heavy load so you can expect that your request will be rejected.

> Reference:
>   [How to avoid getting throttled or blocked in SharePoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online#how-to-decorate-your-http-traffic-to-avoid-throttling)

Comment: I know this comment is long after the question, but the reason about getting the api thottled was that another team performed a migration in business hours. Nothing to do with Azure AD App.